# Axios - DELETE Request With Request Body and Headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, http-delete

I'm using Axios while programming in ReactJS and I pretend to send a DELETE request to my server.

To do so I need the headers:

```
headers: {
  'Authorization': ...
}
```

and the body is composed of

```
var payload = {
    "username": ..
}
```

I've been searching in the inter webs and only found that the DELETE method requires a "param" and accepts no "data".

I've been trying to send it like so:

```
axios.delete(URL, payload, header);
```

or even

```
axios.delete(URL, {params: payload}, header);
```

But nothing seems to work...

Can someone tell me if it's possible (I presume it is) to send a DELETE request with both headers and body and how to do so?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Here is a brief summary of the formats required to send various http verbs with axios:

- `GET`: Two ways

  - First method

    ```js
    axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
      .then(function (response) {
        // Do something
      })
    ```
  - Second method

    ```js
    axios.get('/user', {
        params: {
          ID: 12345
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        // Do something
      })
    ```

  *The two above are equivalent. Observe the `params` keyword in the second method.*
- `POST` and `PATCH`

  ```js
  axios.post('any-url', payload).then(
    // payload is the body of the request
    // Do something
  )

  axios.patch('any-url', payload).then(
    // payload is the body of the request
    // Do something
  )
  ```
- `DELETE`

  ```js
  axios.delete('url', { data: payload }).then(
    // Observe the data keyword this time. Very important
    // payload is the request body
    // Do something
  )
  ```

### Key take aways

- `get` requests optionally need a `params` key to properly set query parameters
- `delete` requests with a body need it to be set under a `data` key

Comment: Your answer makes me wish there was a +2 upvote feature on stack overflow.

Comment: This is the only answer that explains it in details. Thanks it really helped in understanding even others.

Comment: How to send delete request with params, not body?

Comment: @MaFiA, if you want to send delete request with params. You can simply put it in the url using query strings

Comment: Great explanation, saved me from a potential headache. Thank you!

Comment: I can't get this to work. Sending `axios.delete('some-url',{data: someObj})` sends a DELETE message with no body.

Comment: `someObj` is probably null or undefined. Ensure nothing has edited someObj before sending the request

Comment: It is not working i send {data: payload} for delete but still it won't send any request body

Comment: great explain , it works for me

Answer (score 406):

So after a number of tries, I found it working.

**Please follow the order sequence** it's very important else it won't work

```
axios.delete(URL, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: authorizationToken
  },
  data: {
    source: source
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain why your answer works?

Comment: Possibly because `DELETE` should not have request bodies. Maybe there's something in there that prevents this (as it should)

Comment: @Evert that's incorrect, DELETE requests have *not defined semantics* for the body, so you can have the request body, but old implementations may reject the request. IMO you should have the request body, and obsolete the old clients and rotate new clients in their place.

Comment: @VictorPudeyev hey, I understand that the language in the HTTP specification is confusing. Yes a body _may_ appear, but it should have any meaning to the server. So there is never a good reason to add a body to a HTTP DELETE body. So you can add a body, but it's pointless.

Comment: So my original comment is correct. In fact, this a paragraph from the upcoming HTTP spec that echoes this: "A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a DELETE request. Content received in a DELETE request has no defined semantics, cannot alter the meaning or target of the request, and might lead some implementations to reject the request."

Comment: @VictorPudeyev Disclaimer, I helped write this. Reference: https://httpwg.org/http-core/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics-latest.html#DELETE

Comment: @Evert - in your comment on Jun 3 17:11, did you mean "but it SHOULDN'T have any meaning"?

Answer (score 246):

`axios.delete` does supports both request body and headers.

It accepts two parameters: `url` and optional config. You can use `config.data` to set the request body and headers as follows:

```
axios.delete(url, { data: { foo: "bar" }, headers: { "Authorization": "***" } });
```

See here - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897

Comment: The thing is I want to send a body and headers in the same delete request

Answer (score 25):

**axios.***delete* is [passed a url and an optional configuration](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config).

> axios.delete(url[, config])

The fields [available to the configuration can include the headers](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

This makes it so that the API call can be written as:

```
const headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer paperboy'
}
const data = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

axios.delete('https://foo.svc/resource', {headers, data})
```

Comment: This does not work for me... I have `const headers = {'Authorization': ...}` and `data = {'username': ...}` ending up with `axios.delete('http://...', {headers, data})` but the server cannot access the headers...

Comment: The request going out from the browser says different. See this Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gq1maa) and also the request in the browser network tab (https://snag.gy/JrAMjD.jpg). You need to be sure here that you're reading the headers server side the right way or that the request isn't intercepted and tampered with.

Comment: worked for me, I'm using React and Django

Answer (score 17):

For those who tried everything above and still don't see the payload with the request - make sure you have:

```
"axios": "^0.21.1" (not 0.20.0)
```

Then, the above solutions work

```
axios.delete("URL", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      data: {
        var1: "var1",
        var2: "var2"
      },
    })
```

You can access the payload with

```
req.body.var1, req.body.var2
```

Here's the issue:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3335

Comment: exactly. they had issue (#3282) solved in 0.21.0

Answer (score 14):

For Delete, you will need to do as per the following

```
axios.delete("/<your endpoint>", { data:<"payload object">})
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, `axios.delete` supports a request body. 
It accepts two parameters: a `URL` and an optional `config`. That is...

```
axios.delete(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined)
```

You can do the following to set the response body for the delete request:

```
let config = { 
    headers: {
        Authorization: authToken
    },
    data: { //! Take note of the `data` keyword. This is the request body.
        key: value,
        ... //! more `key: value` pairs as desired.
    } 
}

axios.delete(url, config)
```

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, I am using this in my nestJs HttpService delete method as :

this.httpService.delete(apiUrl, { headers: headersRequest, data: deleteBody })

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue I solved it like that:

```
axios.delete(url, {data:{username:"user", password:"pass"}, headers:{Authorization: "token"}})
```

Answer (score 6):

Axios DELETE request does supports similar what POST request does, but **comes in different formats**.

DELETE request payload sample code:

```
axios.delete(url, { data: { hello: "world" }, headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer_token_here" } });
```

POST request payload sample code:

```
axios.post(url, { hello: "world" }, { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer_token_here" } });
```

Noticed that **{ hello: "world" }** is configured in different ways, but both performs same functions.

Answer (score 5):

If we have:

```
myData = { field1: val1, field2: val2 }
```

We could transform the data (JSON) into a string then send it, as a parameter, toward the backend:

```
axios.delete("http://localhost:[YOUR PORT]/api/delete/" + JSON.stringify(myData), 
     { headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token') } }
 )
```

In the server side, we get our object back:

```
app.delete("/api/delete/:dataFromFrontEnd", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    // we could get our object back:
    const myData = JSON.parse(req.params.dataFromFrontEnd)
 })
```

**Note:** the answer from "**x4wiz**" on **Feb 14 at 15:49** is more accurate to the question than mine! My solution is without the "body" (it could be helpful in some situation...)

**Update**: my solution is NOT working when the object has the weight of 540 Bytes (15*UUIDv4) and more (please, check the documentation for the exact value). The solution of "**x4wiz**" (and many others above) is way better. So, why not delete my answer? Because, it works, but mostly, it brings me most of my Stackoverflow's reputation ;-)

Answer (score 4):

i found a way that's works:

```
axios
      .delete(URL, {
        params: { id: 'IDDataBase'},
        headers: {
          token: 'TOKEN',
        },
      }) 
      .then(function (response) {
        
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I hope this work for you too.

Answer (score 4):

this code is generated from post man and it's perfectly work for delete api request with body.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"profile":"false","cover":"true"});

var config = {
  method: 'delete',
  url: 'https://api.fox.com/dev/user/image',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token', 
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score 4):

After decades, I found this working

```
axios.delete(url,{data: payload})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

To send an HTTP DELETE with some headers via `axios` I've done this:

```
  const deleteUrl = "http//foo.bar.baz";
  const httpReqHeaders = {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  // check the structure here: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config
  const axiosConfigObject = {headers: httpReqHeaders}; 

  axios.delete(deleteUrl, axiosConfigObject);
```

The `axios` syntax for different HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) is tricky because sometimes the 2nd parameter is supposed to be the HTTP body, some other times (when it might not be needed) you just pass the headers as the 2nd parameter.

However let's say you need to send an HTTP POST request without an HTTP body, then you need to pass `undefined` as the 2nd parameter.

Bare in mind that according to the definition of the configuration object (https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) you can still pass an HTTP body in the HTTP call via the `data` field when calling `axios.delete`, however for the HTTP DELETE verb it will be ignored.

This confusion between the 2nd parameter being sometimes the HTTP body and some other time the whole `config` object for `axios` is due to how the HTTP rules have been implemented. Sometimes an HTTP body is not needed for an HTTP call to be considered valid.

Answer (score 3):

For Axios DELETE Request, you need to include request payload and headers like this under one JSON object:

```
axios.delete(URL, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': ...
  }, 
  data: {
    "username": ...
  }
})
```

Why can't I do it easily as I do similar to POST requests?

Looking at the [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro), we see that the methods for .get, .post... have a different signature:

```
axios.get(url[, config])
axios.delete(url[, config])
axios.head(url[, config])
axios.options(url[, config])
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
axios.put(url[, data[, config]])
axios.patch(url[, data[, config]])
```

Notice how only `post`, `patch` and `put` have the `data` parameter. This is because these methods are the ones that usually include a body.

Looking at [RFC7231](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html), we see that a DELETE request is not expected to have a body; if you include a body, what it will mean is not defined in the spec, and servers are not expected to understand it.

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

(From the 5th paragraph [here](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#DELETE)).

In this case, if you are also in control of the server, you could decide to accept this body in the request and give it whatever semantics you want. May be you are working with somebody else's server, and they expect this body.

Because DELETE requests with bodies are not defined in the specs, and because they're not common, Axios didn't include them in those method aliases. But, because they're possible, you can do it, just takes a bit more effort.

I'd argue that it would be more conventional to include the information on the url, so you'd do:

```
axios.delete(
  `https://example.com/user/${encodeURIComponent(username}`, 
  { headers: ... }
)
```

or, if you want to be able to delete the user using different criteria (sometimes by username, or by email, or by id...)

```
axios.delete(
  `https://example.com/user?username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}`, 
  { headers: ... }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem...
I solved it by creating a custom axios instance. and using that to make a authenticated delete request..

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const request = axios.create({
        headers: {
            Authorization: token
        }
    });

await request.delete('<your route>, { data: { <your data> }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not realated to axios but might help people tackle the problem they are looking for. PHP doesn't parse post data when preforming a delete call. Axios delete can send body content with a request.
example:

```
//post example
let url = 'http://local.test/test/test.php';
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('asdf', 'asdf');
formData.append('test', 'test');

axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    data: formData,
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})

result: $_POST Array
(
    [asdf] => asdf
    [test] => test
)


// delete example
axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'delete',
    data: formData,
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})

result: $_POST Array
(        
)
```

to get post data on delete call in php use:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.post('/myentity/839', {
  _method: 'DELETE'
})
.then( response => {
  //handle success
})
.catch( error => {
   //handle failure
});
```

Thanks to:
https://www.mikehealy.com.au/deleting-with-axios-and-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above which did not work for me. I ended up just going with PUT (inspiration found [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897#issuecomment-343715381)) and just changed my server side logic to perform a delete on this url call. (django rest framework function override).

e.g.

```
.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8006/api/updatetoken/20`, bayst)
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .catch((error) => { throw error.response.data; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **{data: {key: value}}** JSON object, the example code snippet is given below:

```
// Frontend Code

axios.delete(`URL`, {
        data: {id: "abcd", info: "abcd"},
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });

// Backend Code (express.js)

  app.delete("URL", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const info = req.body.info;
  db.query("DELETE FROM abc_table WHERE id=? AND info=?;", [id, info],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else res.send(result);
    }
  );
});
```