# On click on delete throws error Unknown event handler property `onDelete`

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

System throws below error during on click on the `delete` icon in the Home screen and the delete player is not happening.

```
 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onDelete`. It will be ignored.
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Dialog))
```

`Home.js`

```
 const [deleteDialog, setDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
 const [playerId, setPlayerId] = useState("");

 const deletePlayer = (id) => e => {
    setPlayerId(id);
    setDeleteDialog(true);
  }

  const onDelete = id => () => {
    try {
      Axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player', id);
      setDeleteDialog(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="playerList_header">
          <h1>Players</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="playerList_home_page">
          <div className="grid-container">
            {
              searchResults.map(({ id, image, position, name }) => (
                <div key={id} className="grid-item">
                  {
                    deleteIcon.show && (
                      <span className="deletePlayerButton" onClick={deletePlayer(id)}>
                        <img className="deletePlayerimg" src="/images/delete.png"></img>
                      </span>
                    )}
                  <div>
                    <img alt="" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" key={image} src={image}></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="playerProfile_grid_border">
                    <span className="rec_name_position_data">
                      <h3 key={name}>{name}</h3>
                      <span className="playerPosition_home_tile" key={position}>{position}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>              
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <AlertDialog
    onDelete={onDelete(playerId)}
    open={deleteDialog}
    onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
    playerId={playerId}
  />
    </div>
  );
```

`Dialog.js`

On the `Yes` button `onClick={ onDelete(playerId) }`

```
export default function AlertDialog({ open, onClose, onDelete, playerId }) {
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Delete the player ?"}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          Pressing Yes will delete the player with ID {playerId}.
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary">
          No
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={ onDelete(playerId) } color="primary" autoFocus>
          Yes
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

`Server.js`

```
    app.delete('/service/player', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.id;
    console.log("UserId"+userId);
    const deletePlayer = await UserModel.destroy({
      where:{ id : userId }
    })
    res.status(200).json({ deletePlayer });
    } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass `playerId` to `onDelete` method

**1st way**
Since your onDelete function has a function inside function. Just call `onDelete` and pass playerId

```js
       <Button onClick={onDelete(playerId)} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Yes
        </Button>
```

**2st way**
Rewrite `onDelete` properly. There is no need to put fun inside a fun.

```js
const onDelete = id => {
    try {
      Axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player', id);
      setDeleteDialog(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Now just call provide an inline arrow function to onClick

```js
       <Button onClick={() => onDelete(playerId)} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Yes
        </Button>
```

Comment: When I remove `const onDelete = id => () => {...`  and corrected as suggested `const onDelete = id => {`..it throws Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. and points here .. ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: @soccerway, if you are trying second option you have to change all `{onDelete(playerId)}` to `{() => onDelete(playerId)}` as you are using it 2 places one with `Dialog` and second with `Button` , you might have changed it only one place

Comment: I have changed both places, in Home `<AlertDialog
        onDelete={() => onDelete(playerId)}
        open={deleteDialog}
        onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
        playerId={playerId}
      />` and then <Button onClick={() => onDelete(playerId)} color="primary" autoFocus>

Comment: in home it should look like : `<AlertDialog onDelete={onDelete}`, still inside `Dialog.js` there are 2 places where it is being used as I mentioned above comment

Comment: I have set a break point in the server.js line `const userId = req.body.id;` while loading itself the operation become active at the break point set ( with out clicking on the delete icon ) and become undefined error, createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)

Comment: @soccerway, please show us the updated code, we can't assume what are the changes you have made till now

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have updated the question with most recent changes.

Comment: @soccerway, as per the changes it looks like you are following first method and not second

Comment: @soccerway change `<AlertDialog
    onDelete={onDelete(playerId)}` to `<AlertDialog
    onDelete={onDelete}`

Comment: I have changed to `<AlertDialog onDelete={onDelete}` Now  on click on delet icon `const userId = req.body.id;` is getting as undefined.

Comment: @soccerway, I think you are using delete incorrectly `Axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player', id);` , please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069552/axios-delete-request-with-body-and-headers, after change `console.log(req.body)` in your backend, and your main issue is solved so at least you can accept the answer and upvote as this is now completely diff issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={onClose}
    onDelete={onDelete}
    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
>
```

Dialog component doesn't have prop `onDelete` https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/

Comment: Thank you, now the error got resolved, but deleting the player is not happening though.

Comment: @soccerway Axios request started? Or any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry I have got one more error,didn't saw that. findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Fade))
    in ForwardRef(Fade) (created by ForwardRef(Backdrop))
    in ForwardRef(Backdrop) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Backdrop))) 
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Dialog)) (at Dialog.js:11)
    in AlertDialog (at Home.js:124)
     div (at Home.js:78)